# Queue Creation --- Linked with Custom List ---- Update Queue Status

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I currently have a custom list built with notification workflows.  I would like to create a queue of "reference numbers" with a pending of completed status.  If a reference number is pending, the user has the ability to click on the reference number, which will then prompt the "custom list" to be filled out.  Once completed, the reference status will change from pending to closed.

So I have the list built out, is it possible "without coding" to perform this function.

Limitations:
No access to data view
Quick Edit won't allow to update there are mandatory fields required and my fear is that it may trigger the workflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list view with clickable title field , filtering the items based on status

Add the view on the page you want to. On click on title you will be redirected to display form and then the item can be edited.